# I am getting this error TS2322: Type 'Category' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<any> | null | undefined'

Tags: html, interface, ngfor

I worked on my code a lot but could not debug it ngFor works for other arrays but it is not working for this specific array.*categoryList* is an array but its not working in ngFor loop in DOM
kindly solve this problem.
Thanks in advance

This is my ts file

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Category } from './../category';
import { ProductserveService } from './../../../productserve.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.css']
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {

categoryList!:Category
userLoaded = false;

constructor(private productService:ProductserveService){ }

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.productService.getCategories().subscribe(data=>{
   this.userLoaded=true;
   console.log("Courses data",this.courses)
   console.log("Incoming data: ",data);
   this.categoryList=data;
   this.userLoaded = true;
   // debugger
  });
 }
}
```

This is the interface file
export interface Category{
id:number
categoryName:any;
}

This is my Html Code

```
 <div class="list-group m-auto" *ngIf="userLoaded===true">
      <a *ngFor="let cat of categoryList" class="list-group-item" href="#" > 
         <p>{{cat.categoryName}}</p>
      </a>
  </div>
```